kubernetes upgrade from 1.23. to 1.24
It appears Kubernetes has removed the upgrade documentation to 1.24.
https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/
I know there a couple big changes moving to 1.24 including the deprecation of docker to containerd. I am getting several errors once upgraded. Does anyone have the steps necessary to complete the upgrade?
Ive see a couple things about updating docker shim as well as some cert errors.
Steps I used to upgrade:
kubeadm upgrade apply v1.24.17 sudo yum install -y kubelet-1.24.17-0 kubectl-1.24.17-0 kubernetes-cni-1.1.1-0.x86_64 --disableexcludes=Kubernetes
I have successfully upgraded but am seeing errors
kubelet: Error: failed to parse kubelet flag: unknown flag: --network-plugin
kubelet: --node-ip string IP address (or comma-separated dual-stack IP addresses) of the node. If unset, kubelet will use the node's default IPv4 address, if any, or its default IPv6 address if it has no IPv4 addresses. You can pass '::' to make it prefer the default IPv6 address rather than the default IPv4 address
Please advise.
